# How to check for string value from numeric data type attribute?

Tags: c#, object

For example, If I have an animal object, which has attribute legs which is of type int.
I have to program in such a way that

```
if(animal.legs == 4)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Dog");
}
```

but if user enters the value of legs as a character ("a,...,z") OR null (""), I have to throw an exception.

In other words

```
 if (animal.legs.HasValue ||animal.legs.ToString() == "")
{
   Console.WriteLine("Legs should be integer")
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Dog");
}
```

For the above code, I am always getting "Dog", no matter what the value is. Looks like it is not detecting null or char type. How do I make this int type detect char or null type data.

Comment: @Cyral based on code it is `int?` (but that really should be spelled out in the post - SO is not good place for puzzles like "guess how this code can compile"/"what type it is")

Comment: "but if user enters " - where is the code related to that statement?

Comment: Huh, `int.TryParse()`?

Comment: What is the data type of legs? if it is integer, how can a character come into it? You want to check user input, dont you?

Comment: @DarkKnight thats what I am trying to do , the client has ERP system, where the client can enter character by mistake.

Comment: what is the datatype of `animal.legs`?

Comment: @DarkKnight it is integer

Comment: If it is an integer, `animal.legs.ToString() == ""` this will never be true and you don't have to check for a character. Because, a character couldn't get into that field, in the first place.

Comment: @DarkKnight Yes, you are right, I have to take care of them in memory. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

why not do a int.TryParse on animal.legs

```
int legs = 0;
if(int.TryParse(animal.legs.value, out lets) && legs == 4) {
   Console.WriteLine("Dog");
} else {
   // do your error handling
}
```

Comment: you should not have invalid data inside the class, the try parse should be when the data is entered by the user